# Where does KTor go to for undefined server routes/pages?

Tags: kotlin, networking, ktor

I am not able to understand where does KTor go to for pages/routes that are not defined in my code for a server?
For example, here is my routing code:

```
rounting
{
    webSocket("/connect/{userid}") 
    {
    }

    post("/hello") 
    {
    }
}
```

Now what if a client requests a url which is never defined in the server, say `"/welcome"`?
The client gets a page not found error, but on the server is there a way to define a general route that can be called when an undefined path is requested by a client?
I want to create a list IP addresses that are calling undefined pages so that I can block them later with fail2ban.
I can get the IP address by `call.request.origin.remoteAddress.toString()` but where do I put this code in the routing block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After painful hours of searching I made the following code work for me:

```
val Plugin = createApplicationPlugin("Plugin") {
    onCall { call ->
        call.request.origin.apply {
            //println("Request URL: $scheme://$localHost:$localPort$uri")
            println("*** New http request from: $remoteAddress ++ $remoteHost ++ $remotePort ***")
            println("URL: ${method.value} ++ $version ++ $scheme://$serverHost:${serverPort.toString()}$uri")

            if((uri != "/connect") && (uri != "/hello"))
            {
                println("Since this page does not exist responding with page not found")
                myHTTPrespond(call, 404, "Page not found!", "ERROR", "")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Add this line in Application.kt:

```
install(Plugin)
```